# Javascript funciona en el host pero no en otras pc

Tags: javascript, ajax

La cuestion es la siguiente:

En la pc donde tengo hosteado todos los archivos, todo funciona correctamente, pero si quiero usar el sitio desde otra pc funciona bien excepto por una cosa.

Cuando quiero editar un registro hago un llamado a `javascript:editarRegistro();`
pero en vez de que aparezca el formulario para editar los registros, me devuelve `false`. Creo que es un problema con `ajax`.

EDIT: Esto solo pasa en `Firefox`

Les dejo el código:

```
function editarRegistro(id){
    $('#formulario')[0].reset();
    var url = 'asignaciones/edita_asignacion.php';
        $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:url,
        data:'id='+id,
        success: function(valores){
                var datos = eval(valores);
                $('#reg').hide();
                $('#edi').show();
                $('#pro').val('Edicion');
                $('#id-registro').val(id);
                $('#nombre').val(datos[0]);
                $('#docente').val(datos[1]);
                $('#asignatura').val(datos[2]);
                $('#grupo').val(datos[3]);
                $('#turno').val(datos[4]);
                $('#horario').val(datos[5]);
                $('#estado').val(datos[6]);
                $('#numero').val(datos[7]);
                $('#registra-datos').modal({
                    show:true,
                    backdrop:'static'
                });
            return false;
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tienes que añadir la url base del servidor para que no tengas problemas de acceso cuando cambies de máquina. Te dejo un ejemplo de la aproximación.

```
var base_url = "http://ip_del_servidor:puerto";

function editarRegistro(id){
    $('#formulario')[0].reset();
    var url = base_url  + 'asignaciones/edita_asignacion.php';
        $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:url,
        data:'id='+id,
        success: function(valores){
                var datos = eval(valores);
                $('#reg').hide();
                $('#edi').show();
                $('#pro').val('Edicion');
                $('#id-registro').val(id);
                $('#nombre').val(datos[0]);
                $('#docente').val(datos[1]);
                $('#asignatura').val(datos[2]);
                $('#grupo').val(datos[3]);
                $('#turno').val(datos[4]);
                $('#horario').val(datos[5]);
                $('#estado').val(datos[6]);
                $('#numero').val(datos[7]);
                $('#registra-datos').modal({
                    show:true,
                    backdrop:'static'
                });
            return false;
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda, ahora voy a probar y te digo si se solucionó.

Aclaro que esto solo me pasa en Firefox, en los demás navegadores funciona todo bien, no sé porqué será